# Getting error when I run npm run build . [webpack-cli] TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'CleanwebpackPlugin')

Tags: typescript

```
[webpack-cli] TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'CleanwebpackPlugin').
```

Getting the above error when I run my code.

I have run:

```
npm install --save-dev webpack-cli
```

I expected that it will run clearly without getting any error but it does not.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have a typo in your webpack config. Make sure to use `CleanWebpackPlugin` instead of `CleanwebpackPlugin`

Comment: Showing same error

Comment: Please post your full webpack config